# How to add and run Three Js old code to Vue page component

Tags: vue.js, three.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I would like to know how I can add an old Three Js code to a page component in Vue Js, like just plain javascript grabed on html *script*  tag, without using methods or computed objects from Vue 
 *I'm using node 10.14, Vue-cli 3 and Vue scaffold*

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, one way you could probably do this is to have the JavaScript extracted out into a helper file like `/lib/3JS.js` and then make sure to export it.

Then you could import it into your Vue file and use it there.

Comment: what I exactly would like to do is to add an static external html page to my Vue project, any idea? Thanks :)